# Custom MSBuild task in DBProj

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, visual-studio-dbpro, dbproj

I've created a custom MSBuild task for our database project.  This tasks uses XLSX file to generate reference data insert scripts that get merged into the post deployment script.

I tested this with a test MSBuild proj and it works well.

Now when I integrate it into the real DBProj file, the output of the task is duplicated and I cant see the MSBuild output logging.

So, my questions are:

1) How can I see the full MSBuild logs in Visual Studio? 
2) I'm not sure AfterBuild or BeforeBuild is running twice but maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your MSBuild scripts, set breakpoints, inspect values, etc... See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx